# SSIS error in Visual Studio 0xC0010009

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I've run into an issue with an SSIS package in Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. When I try to open the package I get the following error:

"Microsoft Visual Studio is unable to load this document
Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0010009"

No other information is provided. I have multiple SSIS packages in the solution and the others open. This package opened until I checked it into TFS and then it broke. Any ideas where I could get more information on the error? Or how to solve it?

Comment: Googling this leads me here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345164.aspx Makes me suspect you're using custom / third party components in this package. Perhaps the reference to the DLL containing these components broke when/after checking in and out?

Comment: I'd seen that MSDN article as well, but nope no custom/third party components. All standard out of the box functionality. I did have the BIDs Helper plugin installed but got another dev who didn't to try and he got the same error.

Comment: Could be because it's expecting a password for that file?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is related, but thought I'd throw it out there.

Using SSIS Version 12.0.21005.1 REL, I received the same error and was able to solve it by editing the .dtsx with a good xml editor (hat tip to notepad++).

Basically, ensure it is well formed and all references agree.  For example, in a simple ETL package with OLE DB Source, Transformation, and Output steps in a DataFlow, I found 24 references to each column involved.  For one column, one reference somehow disagreed with the other 23 (it ended up being misspelled; not sure how that happened).  Fixing that solved the error.

Hope that helps.